# The problem of connecting to Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, 23.04

I recently updated Ubuntu, but it no longer connects to Wi-Fi and LAN (I dual-booted the system, even Windows Wi-Fi is disconnected), when it was downloading the new version, I noticed that it has Nvidia firmware packages.  It installs, what should I do?  I even went to advanced mode in root mode and tried to activate the network, but it gives an error